# Should promise's final_suspend always return std::suspend_always?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-coroutine

In Josuttis book on C++20, at §14.2.5, page 476, I read that

> - `final_suspend` defines whether the coroutine should be finally suspended. Here, we specify that we want to do so, which is usually the right thing to do. Note that this member function has to guarantee not to throw exceptions. It should always return `std::suspend_always{}`.

Which to me looks a bit unrealistic. If that quote corresponds to reality, then why couldn't the standard more simply require that `final_suspend` return `void` and the compiler take care of hardcoding `std::suspend_always{}` at the appropriate places?

Indeed, later in the book, §15.7.3, page 536, an awaiter other than `std::suspend_always{}` is returned from `final_suspend`. This `FinalAwaiter` is used to implement symmetric transfer, and it has the same `await_ready` and `await_resume` as `std::suspend_always`, but a different `await_suspend`, which returns a coroutine handle (either the one to transfer control to, or a dummy no-op coroutine to cause the control to go back to the caller just like we were returning `void` or `true`)

```cpp
struct FinalAwaiter {
  bool await_ready() noexcept { return false; }
  std::coroutine_handle<> await_suspend(CoroTask::CoroHdl h) noexcept {
    if (h.promise().contHdl) {
      return h.promise().contHdl;
    } else {
      return std::noop_coroutine();
    }
  }
  void await_resume() noexcept {}
};
```

But still I guess the quoted text is meant to say something interesting.

Comment: There is no requirement that `final_suspend` return `suspend_always`. The book presumably provides a justification for this claim, or maybe there is some context to the statement that is missing from your question.

Comment: @RaymondChen, I've addeed some context. Is that enough?

Comment: "which is usually the right thing to do". So if you want to suspend then you should return `suspend_apways`.

Comment: "*Indeed, later in the book, an awaiter other than std::suspend_always{} is returned from final_suspend.*" Well, what was it? What did it return, and what was that object trying to accomplish?

Comment: @NicolBolas, I've added the missing info, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to say that `final_suspend` should "always suspend", rather than "always return `std::suspend_always`". [A coroutine is considered to be `done` if it is suspended at its final-suspend point](http://eel.is/c++draft/coroutine.handle#observers-3). So if a coroutine flows past this point without suspending, then the coroutine is over, but `coroutine_handle::done()` will not be `true`.

Returning `suspend_always` is merely one way of always suspending in `final_suspend`. You can use any other awaitable, so long as `await_ready` returns `true`. This `AwaitFinal` class is used to start a chained continuation of another coroutine if such a coroutine has been registered with the promise. But it still always suspends.

Comment: If a coroutine flows past `final_suspend`, then the coroutine handle is destroyed, so the question of whether it is `done()` or not is moot. It is fine to flow past `final_suspend` if you know that there are no outstanding copies of the coroutine handle. (Indeed, if you suspend in `final_suspend` when there are no outstanding copies of the coroutine handle, then the coroutine handle will leak, because there will be nobody around to destroy the handle, seeing as nobody has a copy of it.)

Comment: @NicolBolas, _so long as `await_ready` returns `false`_, maybe, considering that `suspend_always::await_ready` also returns `false`?

Comment: @RaymondChen, how can that (`final_suspend` being called with when no outstanding copies of the coroutine handle are around) happen? If we are flowing into `final_suspend`, it means the coroutine is not suspended, right? In which case either it was never suspended since it was called (not even by the initial suspend point) or `itsHandle.resume()` was called and blocked, so how can `itsHandle` get destroyed before we come back from `final_suspend`?

Comment: One way you can reach `final_suspend` with no outstanding copies of the coroutine handle is if the coroutine handle was never given out in the first place. Example: [`fire_and_forget`](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/blob/9e89b5c9fe3bb14ec4842ff54ea444a26c4495b0/strings/base_coroutine_threadpool.h#L696). More generally, any outstanding copies of the coroutine handle have been discarded, so there is nobody waiting for the coroutine to complete.

Comment: _You can use any other awaitable, so long as `await_ready` returns `true`_ **and** `await_resume` does not return `false` nor the handle to the very coroutine for which `final_suspend` is being called, right?